# Workaround to return a lens from a monadic action

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens

Ran into this issue when playing with [today's advent of code problem](http://adventofcode.com/day/23).

Say I have:

```
data Cache = Cache { _a :: Int, _b :: Int }
makeLenses ''Cache

type Register = Lens' Cache Int
```

Using Parsec, I can parse the character 'a' as `a :: Register` and the character 'b' as `b :: Register`.

```
register = a <$ char 'a' <|> b <$ char 'b'
```

which, alone, compiles just fine.

The trouble is when I give `register` the explicit type `Stream s m Char => ParsecT s u m Register`, ghc complains that it wants to give it the type `(Functor f, Stream s m Char) => ParsecT s u m ((Int -> f Int) -> Cache -> f Cache)`.

I think I understand its reasoning - it wants to float the typeclass constraints out as a far as possible; this is just slightly inconvenient to me for purposes of documenting `register`.

Is there a standard workaround for situations like this?

Answer (score 1):

The solution that worked for me was to use [`ALens`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.13/docs/Control-Lens-Lens.html#t:ALens) rather than `Lens`, as

> This type can also be used when you need to store a Lens in a container, since it is rank-1.

Then I just replaced my `Lens` operators `^.` and `%~` with their `ALens` equivalents, `^#` and `#%~`.

Comment: Another option is to use a `WrappedLens`, which will maintain the polymorphism and avoid any possible need to convert the `ALens` to a `Lens`, which will cost you a bit. Or do that by hand by making `Register` a rank 2 newtype.